# iReports, groups within sub datasets

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Could anyone can help me with grouping subdataset query in iReports 4.5.

I wan to use these elements:

http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/schema.reference.html#group

like in normal report group I create in main report query (report group).

I type `groupHeader` and `groupFooter` section in `<group>` but errors apears

I want to use also atributes like `isStartNewPage`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately groups in subdatasets are only really useful for calculating variables such as subtotals for charts.

What you are probably looking for a is a subreport.

You can make it fit in seamlessly. Make it full width and if using iReport delete all the unnecessary bands. `$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}` will pass the same parameters to the subreport.

```
<band height="10">
    <subreport>
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="10"/>
        <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "MainReport_MySubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
    </subreport>
</band>
```